# React useState(), what is the correct way to wait for multiple setState() calls?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In a function inside a functional react component I may update multiple state variables. How can I ensure all state changes have taken place before running the next function.

Below, for example, imagine that calculateScore() is triggered on some event (perhaps some clicks in a game) and adds to the value of either a, b or both. I then wan't to run determineWinner(). How can I run determineWinner() in a way which ensures **both** setA and setB have completed their asynchronous runs so that both a and b are up-to-date (after a single calculateScore() run)?

I didn't find this in the docs or while searching around for a while here on stackOverflow.

Example

```
function MyComponent() {
    let [a, setA] = useState(0);
    let [b, setB] = useState(0);
    let [winnerText, setWinnerText] = useState("")

    function determineWinner() {
        if (a > b) {
            // Note, I don't want this to happen if the score ends up equal after both setA and setB from calculateScore() completes.
            setWinnerText("A won!")
        }
    }

    function calculateScore(aShouldIncrease, bShouldIncrease) {
        if (aShouldIncrease) setA(prevA => prevA + 1);
        if (bShouldIncrease) setB(prevB => prevB + 1);

        determineWinner(); // Doesn't work to run it here, since setA and setB are asynchronous.
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        determineWinner(); // Not guaranteed to work here, since perhaps only setA has completed so far and not setB? Right?
    }, [a, b])

    determineWinner(); // Even if we imagined I had some other condition to prevent it from being run prematurely, it may run when only a or only b has changed, right?

    return <h1>{ winnerText }</h1>
}
```

I realize I could solve it by making all the calculations within the calculateScore without setting state, but I wonder if there is some point in react where I can be sure all setState() functions started from within a single function call will be completed.

Comment: I think your useEffect implementation should work properly. Alternatively you may use useMemo or useCallback depending on your requirements

Comment: Why would you need to store determined winner in state if it is completely dependent on other values. Just compute it in-place. `<h1>{ a > b ? "A won" : b > a ? "B won" : "" }</h1>`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes, in my minimalistic example, but in my real code, the game should end as soon as someone wins, and run a bunch of different code. Imagine if I also wanted to count the number of wins, for example. I think David's answer below is the best solution.

Comment: @Ylor It doesn't matter how complex your computations are. If it is computable then compute. There is a special hook `useMemo` to memoize results if a computation is too heavy. David's answer is not the best mainly because having effect would cause your component to rerender: scores change -> render -> effect -> winner change -> render.

Comment: Yes, I see how your suggestion would be the best in the example I provided. But if I only made the change you suggest and not David's, there could be a situation where setA finishes executing and then "A won" is shown. Further compuptations might conclude the game is finished, redirect to another view and send some request to add 1 to total wins for A on the server, for example. But then in the next instant, setB finishes executing, adding 1 score to b and it turns out it should have been a draw. I Hope you understand what I mean. So setting both values together must be best in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically it sounds like you want to perform an action when "the game score" is updated, not when any individual value therein is updated.  So there's a level of encapsulation not accounted for in the current code.

Keep the "game state" in one state object rather than two.  For example, consider this:

```
const [scores, setScores] = useState({a: 0, b: 0});
```

Then updating that state would be a single "set" operation:

```
function calculateScore(aShouldIncrease, bShouldIncrease) {
    const newScores = { ...scores };
    if (aShouldIncrease) {
        newScores.a++;
    }
    if (bShouldIncrease) {
        newScores.b++;
    }
    if (aShouldIncrease || bShouldIncrease) {
        setScores(newScores);
    }
}
```

Then since only one state object was updated, you can trigger the effect with just that dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    determineWinner();
}, [scores]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense! Perhaps there are more complex scenarios where it would make more sense to use separate state variables - I'm not sure - but at least in my case and many other's this seems to be the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateScore(aShouldIncrease, bShouldIncrease) {
   unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
     if (aShouldIncrease) setA(prevA => prevA + 1);
     if (bShouldIncrease) setB(prevB => prevB + 1);

      determineWinner();
   });
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would solve the problem. Wouldn't the above code run into the same problem - i.e. that setA and setB may not both (or either) have completed before determineWinner() is run? Or am I missing something?